# I can't create a second partition in Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, core-storage

When I go to my disk utility, my main hard gives me results like this

[image]

It's showing capacity 499gb but only remaining 10mb. Now please see the second image

[image: please help me what i do]

What's happening with my Mac?

Comment: using the first image you posted above... click on the partition tab and you are ready to go... what is your problem here ??

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group on your physical disk named "Macintosh HD" containing a Logical Volume also named "Macintosh HD". The latter is the volume usually visible on your desktop (depending on your Finder settings). The Logical Volume Group already extends across your whole physical disk except an invisible EFI partition (200 MB) and an invisible Recovery HD (~650 MB).

The Logical Volume (499 GB with 456 GB free space) extends across your whole Logical Volume Group.

As a result you can't create a second partition (including the invisible partitions in fact a forth) because you have no unallocated space on your physical disk.

To create a second partition you have to resize the whole CoreStorage stack to create a non-CoreStorage volume or resize the Logical Volume to create a second CoreStorage Logical Volume first.

Comment: okay i understand so how i can do it any solution

Comment: @Hassan Do you plan to install Windows 7/8 in the future?

Comment: Thanks buddy its solved i just changed the name of my harddrive and its done .

Comment: @Hassan ?? Renaming may help distinguish the CS Volume Group from the CS Volume but doesn't allow you  to create a 2nd partition.